# erron on vscode gradle

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

i have one error that's is impossible for me to solve, what kind of problem is this shit?
I've searched for many ways to fix this but i don't have found it nothing for this problem on vscode only for android studio, someone can help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO2gY.jpg)

this impossibilite me to deploy my application in a on virtual android always stop in this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run

```
flutter run --verbose
```

and try to upload new image error.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it whats happening man,in flutter in pub dev they gave changed the ways of splash screen it's not using the drawables anymore,we must create in lib paste the archive called Splash-Screen.dart and code all the splash screen rsrsrs but i'll appreciate your bro,and i'm very thankfull for that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).